# AI third person controller enemy legs not moving but character is and waypoints moving with enemy. Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and C#.  The problem that I have is that my AI third person controller enemy's legs are not moving, even though the character itself is moving.  The enemy is moving to the first waypoint and then will not turn around to go to the other waypoint.  I had this working perfectly before but I accidentally overwrote the prefab I had set to the enemy.  The navmeshagent is set to the enemy and the box collider is not on the ground, but it is covering the enemy. I have the navmeshagent at the default settings as well. The code is unaltered from before I killed my enemy the first time. So it has to be something in the developer.  Also the waypoint spheres are in an empty gameObject.

[image: First part of code]

[image: Second/last part of code]

breakpoints are inserted in the highlighted areas

Comment: Perhaps add the code you're using? It helps to understand the context of the question.

Comment: Just edited the post to fit the code (all of it is in images).

Comment: @RaahulPathak It would be more useful to copy and paste your code in a formatted fashion instead of linking code in pictures. Links disappear over time.

Comment: @Eliasar, The reason I linked my code through images this time is that I don't know where/or if I messed up.  I posted it through images since it is about 100 or so lines of code.  But thank you for the comment.  I will start doing that in the future.

Comment: @RaahulPathak if you are interested in answers here you should start doing it right ahead and not wait until the future ;)